# How to configure an Android library that uses Firebase to authenticate users to use google-services.json from an app that uses it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-library

I'm trying to implement an Android library that uses Firebase authentication to authenticate users. It consists of one class that looks like this:

```
class FirebaseRepository {

    fun signInWithUsernameAndPassword(username: String, password: String): Task<AuthResult> {
        return Firebase.auth
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
    }

}
```

I'm using this library in my app as follows:

```
fun signInWithUsernameAndPassword() {
    FirebaseRepository().signInWithUsernameAndPassword("bobapp@gmail.com", "bobapp")
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("exampleapp", "signInWithEmail:success")
            } else {
                Log.w("exampleapp", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
            }
        }
}
```

When building the app I'm getting an error that `google-services.json` could not be found for `auth` library. I would not like to register my library in Firebase as a separate app, but instead I would like to use `google-services.json` file from the app. How can I do that?

**Edit:**

Here's the app's `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.exampleapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.4'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(path: ':auth')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

}
```

Here's the library's build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.auth'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation project(path: ':apimanager')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'

}
```

Structure of the project is:

```
android/
  app/
  auth/
```

The error message that I'm getting when building the project:

```
Execution failed for task ':auth:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.auth'
```

But I've managed to find the solution:

1. In `build.gradle` file of `auth` I need to change the `namespace` to be `com.example.exampleapp`.
2. Add the `google-services.json` from the `app` into the `auth`.

Still is there some better way to solve this problem without the need to change the `auth` library every time it is used in a different app?

Comment: Please edit the question to show your application's configuration (what did you do to set this up?), what you are doing to cause the error, the actual error message itself.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior using the instructions you provide.

Comment: I will add that if the main Android app module is already initializing the Firebase SDK, there is nothing you need to do to use it in a library module other than import the dependencies you want to use, and start using them by their static accessors (like `Firebase.auth` as you are now).  This only works if your module code is invoked only after the Firebase init is finished in the app module.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited the question. I've tried using Firebase with the static accessors, but I get the following error: Execution failed for task ':auth:processDebugGoogleServices'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only apply Firebase configuration to the main app module of your app.  You can't apply it to library modules.

You should:

- Remove the com.google.gms.google-services plugin from your library
- Remove the google-services.json file from your library

You can leave the Firebase dependencies, since they are required to compile your library, regardless of what the app module needs itself.

Your library should absolutely not access any Firebase APIs until the after app module has fully initialized Firebase.

Comment: I could do that. But I need the com.google.gms.google-services plugin because I'm planning to implement signInWithGoogle method.

Comment: Why would you need the plugin for that?  signInWithGoogle is just an API that you can use as a dependency.  All the plugin does is read the google-services.json file at build time, and arrange to automatically initialize Firebase by injecting the code to do that in the app module. That only needs to be done once in the app module's manifest.  The APIs can be consumed at runtime from anywhere else without the plugin.

Comment: You are correct. I thought that plugin was used for more then the Firebase initialization. I've deleted the plugin and google-services.json and I am able to use objects/classes like Identity from gms and build project successfully.